# Getting a weird error in ruby while trying to pass an array to a method

Tags: ruby

The following code:

```
def array_sum(*n)
  sum = 0
  0.upto(a.length-1) do |i|
    sum += n[i]
  end
  return sum
end

a = (1..5).to_a
puts array_sum(a)
```

gives me an ambiguous error:

> "/Users/Josh/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Test/Euler7.cgi:10:in `array_sum': undefined local variable or method`a' for main:Object (NameError)
>       from /Users/Josh/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Test/Euler7.cgi:17"

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing ambiguous about the error. You probably meant to write `n.length - 1` instead of `a.length - 1`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. No copy pasting, I'm just an idiot. I'll accept your answer as soon as stackOverFlow allows me

Answer (score 2):

While Sergio Tulentsev's answer is the appropriate solution here, you might be also interested in a one-line implementation of this algorithm:

```
puts (1..5).reduce(:+)
```

Comment: `reduce(:+)` means, call the method `+` while iterating over the elements of the array. You can also use `:-` or any other method (of the elements) that accepts an argument.